# Why is the input value undefined after validation?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple problem that I cannot seem to fix. I simply want to be able to display the value of the input Name field after entering your name and clicking submit. However, undefined seems to occur.

Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix? The code is below:

```js
var name = document.querySelector('#withJS input:first-of-type'),
    date = document.querySelector('#withJS input:not(:first-of-type)'),
    errorMsg = document.querySelector('#withJS .errorMsg');
  
  errorMsg.style.display='none';

  function validateForm() {
    alert(name.value);
    /*
    if(name.length == 0){
    errorMsg.style.display='block';
      errorMsg.textContent='Enter Name';
    }
    */
  }
```

```css
#noJS, #withJS {
  background: lightgreen;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
}
#withJS {
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.errorMsg {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id='withJS'>
<form>
Name:<br>
<input type="text">
  <br>
  Date:<br>
<input type="date">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='validateForm()'>
</form>
  <div class='errorMsg'>error message here</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variable `name` you've declared clashes with the `window` attribute `name`.  Change the name of that variable, i.e: `fname`.

```js
var fname = document.querySelector('#withJS input:first-of-type'),
    date = document.querySelector('#withJS input:not(:first-of-type)'),
    errorMsg = document.querySelector('#withJS .errorMsg');
  
  errorMsg.style.display='none';

  function validateForm() {
    alert(fname.value);
    /*
    if(name.length == 0){
    errorMsg.style.display='block';
      errorMsg.textContent='Enter Name';
    }
    */
  }
```

```css
#noJS, #withJS {
  background: lightgreen;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
}
#withJS {
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.errorMsg {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id='withJS'>
<form>
Name:<br>
<input type="text">
  <br>
  Date:<br>
<input type="date">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='validateForm()'>
</form>
  <div class='errorMsg'>error message here</div>
</div>
```